# docker-compose error: "no such file or directory" on Windows

Tags: python, windows, docker, flask

I am following along with this [tutorial](https://realpython.com/dockerizing-flask-with-compose-and-machine-from-localhost-to-the-cloud/) for running a Flask server using Docker. I am working on a Windows machine so I am using Docker Toolbox.

Once I enter the command to create the database table:

```
docker-compose run web /usr/local/bin/python create_db.py
```

I get the following error:

> Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:
>   container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec:
>   \"C:/Program Files/Git/usr/local/bin/python\": stat C:/Program
>   Files/Git/usr/local/bin/python: no such file or directory": unknown

I am not sure why I am getting this error, any suggestions on how to fix this error would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command fails because windows tries to parse the path, this can be circumvented by quoting the path:

```
docker-compose run web python create_db.py
```

If the above fails a double dash can be used:

```
docker-compose run web -- "/usr/local/bin/python create_db.py"
```

Comment: When I use the first command I receive the same original error. When I use the second command I receive the error `Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"--\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown`

Comment: I updated the answer, try using double quotes `"//usr` at the start

Comment: I tried the updated command. I still get the same error unfortunately

Comment: Try running it without the local path, the path should be in the environment path and thus not needed

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the current directory, and then to execute the script :

```sh
docker-compose run web bash -c "cd /usr/local/bin/; python create_db.py"
```